# How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to Japanese

Tags: pronunciation, chinese

I am working on an art project that I would like to collect the hundreds of different transliterations of 「中文」 *zhōng wén* in Mandarin Chinese. (Pronunciation available here: [https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/中文](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87))

How can I transliterate *zhōng wén* in Japanese? (For example, "zhong wen" would be the closest pronunciation in English.)

Comment: ONE more example, the two characters Cantonese pronunciation in English ‘zung man’ different transliterations : ‘dschong man’ (closest pronunciation in German), ‘زونج من’ (closest pronunciation iin Arabic)

Comment: There are three close votes already. I don't see how this question is different from the many requests for accurate transliterations of unknown names.

Comment: 中文 = 中国語 I don't get your point.

Comment: Are transliterations against the rules?

Comment: @Blavius Not as far as I know. Like I said, we have open questions http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42167/1628, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14790/1628, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6096/1628. I don't see how "Yana" or "Aimad (عماد)" or "João" are substantially different from "zhōng wén". (Questions for transliteration of Japanese names seem to be [closed](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23278/1628), but that doesn't seem to be relevant to this question.)

Answer (score 2):

In Japanese 中文 is read ちゅうぶん *chūbun* and means "[literary] Chinese (language)".

[Apparently](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/tanakaccci/e/31b832b3d1b31d89d6783298862036d1/) the Mandarin pronunciation is usually transliterated as チョンウェン *chon wen* (or チュンウェン *chun wen*).

Comment: We usually write 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation (= zhōng wén) as チョンウェン in Katakana.